# Are recommendations for programming tutorials/resources on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, policy

Normally I would take programming questions to Stack Overflow, but I believe they're starkly against recommendations in most cases.  However, I feel that asking for programming tutorials or resources risks being off topic for this site.

I would argue that some learning resources such as [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn) are in fact software and would fall under this site's scope.  Does this mean I can only ask for recommendations of software packages that teach programming skills?  Can I ask for recommendations in other areas such as website and print resources?

Comment: I don't understand why you consider Codecademy to be software, but I'm unfamiliar with it, so I might have missed something. As far as I can tell, it's not something you run, more like something you read. It's content, not software. [Howtos](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/882/are-how-tos-on-topic) and [websites](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-i-ask-for-recommended-websites) are off-topic. We only do software recommendations, not recommendations of content that's related to software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they are not.

While such content is valuable, it needs its own set of criteria for distinguishing good questions and good answers. We focus on stuff that can be executed on computers, "software", rather then stuff that you consume, "content".

Tutorials etc. are content, not software. That makes them off-topic here. Maybe one (you?) could create an own SE site for this (compare English.SE vs. English-Language-Learners.SE) where such recommendations would be on-topic. I know I would be interested in it.

Comment: In fact I have here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89684/educational-resource-recommendations : D

Comment: Alas it did not succeed :-(

Answer (score 6):

#### Short answer

No.

#### TL;DR

As Gilles already pointed out in his comment: SR is about recommending *software* matching *specific requirements* – and not "general resources", tutorials, howtos, or websites. For details, also see related questions:

- [Can I ask for recommended websites?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/185)
- [Are how-to's on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185)
- [Is asking for sample, illustrative code on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185)
- [Questions that do not ask for recommended software on topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/703/185)